# Evaluate: $ \displaystyle\int \frac{9x^2 - 30x - 73}{(x - 4)(x^2 - x - 12)} \; dx$ Partial fractions

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

Evaluate: $\;  \displaystyle\int \frac{9x^2 - 30x - 73}{(x - 4)(x^2 - x - 12)} \; dx$

I couldn't find A, how to find A in the partial fractions below?

$$\int \frac{9x^2 - 30x - 73}{(x - 4)(x+3)(x-4)} \; dx $$

$$\int \frac{9x^2 - 30x - 73}{(x - 4)^2(x+3)} \; dx $$

Solving what's inside integral:

$$\frac{9x^2 - 30x - 73}{(x - 4)^2(x+3)} \; dx = \frac{A}{(x-4)} + \frac{B}{(x-4)^2} + \frac{C}{(x+3)} $$

->

$$ 9x^2 - 30x - 73 = A(x-4)(x+3) + B (x+3) + C(x-4)^2$$

$$x = 4, \;\; 9 \cdot 4^2 - 30 \cdot 4 - 73 = A \cdot 0 + B (4 + 3) + C \cdot 0  $$

$$B = \frac{-49}{7} = -7$$

$$x = -3, \;\; 9 \cdot (-3)^2 - 30 \cdot (-3) - 73 = A \cdot 0 + B \cdot 0 + C (-7)^2 $$

$$C = \frac{98}{49} = 2$$

I tried to find A by plugging in the now-known values of B and C, but to no avail. How do I find A?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^2$ is $9$. It is also $A+C$, and we know $C$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't know why you're saying "It is also A+C"

Comment: If you look at your second displayed equation, the one that starts with $9x^2-30x-73=$, and *imagine* expanding the right-hand side, you will get $(A+C)x^2+\text{stuff}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No I won't, I get: $ 9x^2 - 30x - 73 = Ax^2 - Ax - 12A +Bx+3B + Cx^2  - 8Cx + 16C$

Comment: Yes, and the coefficient of $x^2$ in your expansion is $A+C$. We don't need the rest of the stuff in your expansion, since it is not required for finding $A$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas >"We don't need the rest of the stuff in your". Why do you say that? How do you know... there are other terms with x, you can't just compare coefficients of x^2 on both sides... what if there also were x^4 or x^3....

Comment: We are choosing $A,B,C$ so that  polynomial  on the left and the one on the right are *identically equal*. So the coefficients of $x^2$ must match, the coefficients of $x$ must match, the constant terms must match. In principle, your expansion gives us three linear equations in the three unknowns $A,B,C$. However, we already know $B$ and $C$ through substitution tricks. So all we need is $A$, and that can be found by just comparing coefficients of $x^2$. It could also alternately be found by comparing coefficients of $x$, or by comparing constant terms. However, these are a bit more messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your second displayed equation, the one that starts with $9x^2-30x-73=$.  The coefficients of $x^2$ on the left-hand side and right-hand side must match.

The coefficient of $x^2$ on the left-hand side is $9$.  *Imagine* expanding the right-hand side, you will get $(A+C)x^2+\text{stuff}$.

So $9=A+C$. We know $C$, so we know $A$.

**Remark:** In principle, we are trying to find numbers $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that the polynomial $9x^2-30x-73$ is **identically equal** to the polynomial $A(x-4)(x+3)+B(x+3)+C(x-4)^2$.

One way to find such $A,B,C$ is to *match coefficients*. That gives us three linear equations in the three unknowns $A,B,C$, which we solve in the usual way. That can be tedious, and we can $B$ and $C$ in this case by using substitution tricks. We can also find $A$ by a substitution trick, for example by letting $x=0$. However, to find $A$ we instead went partly back to basics and used matching of coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Since $B=-7$ and $C=2$, we can say that $9x^2 -30x-73=A(x-4)(x+3)-7(x+3)+2(x-4)^2$. Try plugging in $0$ or any other value other than $4$ or $-3$ for $x$ and solving for $A$.

Comment: it's not any other value, I can't use 4 or -3. Unless I expand.

Comment: You are right. I edited my post.

Comment: I tried 0 and I got 7.